# SQL Query to get the Result in One Scan without using analytical function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table named Employee Which has 3 columns EmployeeID Award Date and Award

```
| EMPOYEEID | AwardDate | Award
|1          | 10-03-2018| EOY
|1          | 14-08-2018| EBF
|2          | 10-03-2017| EOY
|3          | 10-03-2016| EOY
|2          | 31-12-2017| COINS
|1          | 31-08-2017| COINS
```

Using SQL query in oracle, What i want is without using analytical function i want to get the first award and last award date for each employee in one scan.
Below is and example

`ID|LastDate  | FirstAward
  1|10-03-2018|31-08-2017
  2|31-12-2017|10-03-2017`

Comment: mysql <> Oracle, which one are you working on? Also, show us what you have  attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate function

```
select EMPOYEEID, max(AwardDate) LastDate, min(AwardDate) FirstAward
from table_name t1
group by EMPOYEEID
```